# Unable to find location of Hibernate configurations for changing dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss7.x

As a newbie in web applications I'm finding myself stranded from time to time. Currently I am trying to fix a web application (written/set up in Jboss) that has been built by someone else who I can no longer ask for help. The application deploys correctly. However, a warning is given when deploying about the dialect of Hibernate. While not a major issue, I would like to change the dialect. Warning below:

```
10:29:10,935 WARN  [Oracle9Dialect] The Oracle9Dialect dialect has been deprecated; use either Oracle9iDialect or Oracle10gDialect instead
```

However, I cannot find the location where to adjust this. I cannot find a hibernate.properties, hibernate.cfg.xml or other configuration file anywhere.
For several reasons I have to run the application on jBoss EAP 5.2. This has some consequences for the Hibernate set up, I guess.

I am using Jboss 7.1.1; installed JDK is 1.7.0_60. I also use Maven 3.0.4 and Hibernate 4.2.7. I am a little wary to install a newer version of Hibernate as I am not sure what the consequences will be and which configurations I need to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using Hibernate as a JPA provider, you may look for `META-INF/persistence.xml`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that, but cannot find a persistence.xml anywhere either. It seems as Hibernate is not configured at all, but yet it is 'mentioned' during deployment.

Comment: is it built on Spring? if yes then check configuration where you are creating sessionfactory bean. paste configuration files here.

Comment: No, I do not think it is built on Spring. The place the sessionfactory is built looks like this: `public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { this.filterConfig = filterConfig; sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(); } ` However, I cannot find the HibernateUtil.class, it is not configured in the project, but from Hibernate itself (is that correct?). Hibernate is still quite a mystery to me.

Comment: By default `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()` build session factory from hibernate.cfg.xml. it might be possible that application has own `HibernateUtil` class. there could be Java file with `@Configuration` annotation also.

Comment: I cannot find a HibernateUtil.class in the application itself. What kind of Java file do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies.
A short-term solution was found in copying the HibernateUtil.class and pasting this file into the source, and setting the dialect in that file.
However, when trying to solve an unrelated problem, I found that there were several more classes and files I needed but couldn't find. At last I've been able to find these missing files in a total different directory (which was still in the repository and not checked-out), and it also included a HibernateUtil.class and hibernate.cfg.xml.
This problem seemed to be quite application-specific, but at last it is solved :)